# Topology of the set of polynomials with bounded real algebraic varieties (inside the v. s. of polynomials in $n$ variables and up to degree $d$)

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gn.general-topology, real-algebraic-geometry, vector-spaces, real-algebra

Set $x=(x_{1}, \dots, x_{n}).$ Consider the set $\mathbb{R}[x]_{d}$ of polynomials with coef. in $\mathbb{R}$ in $n$ variables up to degree $d.$ This set can be seen as a finite-dimensional vector space with basis formed by all the monomials up to degree $d$ in $n$ variables and thus endowed accordingly with a(n Euclidean) topology coming naturally from this vector space structure. Now consider particularly the subset $\mathbb{R}0[x]_{d}$ of polynomials in $\mathbb{R}[x]_{d}$ that, when restricted to a real line, have only real zeros (see Section 2.1 [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0306180.pdf) where RZ polynomials are defined). Finally, take the subset $b\mathbb{R}0[x]_{d}\subsetneq\mathbb{R}0[x]_{d}$ of polynomials defining **bounded real** algebraic varieties. Does $b\mathbb{R}0[x]_{d}$ has non-empty interior in $\mathbb{R}[x]_{d}$ with respect to the Euclidean topology previously mentioned?

I really intuit that this question has to be easily answerable and that $b\mathbb{R}0[x]_{d}$ has in fact non-empty interior in $\mathbb{R}[x]_{d}$ but I cannot see how to prove it right now. Thanks for any insight!

Comment: I think you need $d$ to be even, otherwise $bR0[x]_d$ is contained in the proper subspace $R0[x]_{d-1}$. If $d$ is even then the interior of $bR0[x]_d$ does seem to be nonempty; a small neighborhood of a polynomial whose real vanishing set is a disjoint union of $d/2$ concentric spheres should do the job.